# Input data is not stored as expected in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have form with dynamic tables in it where i can add/remove rows, I want to save the data into `Transaction_in` and `Transaction_in_detail` table, when i save the data to `Transaction_in` table is saved as expected but not with `Transaction_in_detail`.

When I submit the data no matter how many row I put inside the table the saved data inside `Transaction_in_detail` table always give me 10 all null rows.

[image: Transaction_in_detail table]

**Store Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'supplier_id' => 'required',
        'transaction_in_date' => 'required|before_or_equal:today',
        'device_type_id' => 'required',
        'device_brand_id' => 'required',
        'device_spec' => 'required|max:255',
        'price' => 'required',
        'amount' => 'required',
        'total_price' => 'required',
        'keterangan' => 'Nullable',
    ]);

    $transaction_in = new Transaction_in();
    $transaction_in->idTransaction_in = "0";
    $transaction_in->Supplier_id = $request->input('supplier_id');
    $transaction_in->tanggal_transaksi = $request->input('transaction_in_date');
    $transaction_in->save();

    foreach ($transaction_in as $tin) {
        $tdin[] = [
            'Transaction_in_id' => $transaction_in->id[$tin],
            'DeviceType_id' => $transaction_in->device_type_id[$tin],
            'DeviceBrand_id' => $transaction_in->device_brand_id[$tin],
            'spek_device' => $transaction_in->device_spec[$tin],
            'harga_device' => $transaction_in->price[$tin],
            'jumlah_device' => $transaction_in->amount[$tin],
            'total_harga_device' => $transaction_in->total_price[$tin]
        ];
        Transaction_in_detail::insert($tdin);
    }
    $transaction_in->update(['idTransaction_in' => sprintf('TIN-%04d', $transaction_in->id)]);

    return redirect('/transactionsin')->with('success', 'Transaction success');
}
```

The following is the output from `dd()`.

[image: $dd output]

I don't know where the mistake is; this is the model.

**Transaction_in Model**

```
class Transaction_in extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function get_suppliers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class, 'Supplier_id');
    }
    public function get_devicetypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DeviceType::class, 'DeviceType_id');
    }
    public function get_devicebrands()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DeviceBrand::class, 'DeviceBrand_id');
    }
}
```

**Transaction_in_detail Model**

```
class Transaction_in_detail extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function get_transction_in_id()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Transaction_in::class, 'Transaction_in_id');
    }
    public function get_devicetypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DeviceType::class, 'DeviceType_id');
    }
    public function get_devicebrands()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DeviceBrand::class, 'DeviceBrand_id');
    }
}
```

The Form is inside `Transaction_in` View and that `Store Controller` is from `transaction_inController`, both `DeviceType_id` and `DeviceBrand_id` are foreign key.

This is `Transaction_in` table in database work as expected.

[image: Transaction_in table]

Comment: You're looping through an Eloquent model with that foreach. I don't know why you would do that unless your database is badly designed.

Comment: Your models do not follow the naming convention, therefore you should set the `$table` property of the models to the table name. The official documentation explains this.

Comment: iterating the Model will just give you the few public properties defined on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove foreach in your function and you can insert data directly to transaction in detail table

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        ...
        $transaction_in->save();
        for($i=0; $i < count($request->device_brand_id); $i++){
         $tdin[] = array(
          'Transaction_in_id' => $transaction_in->id,
          'DeviceType_id' => $request->device_type_id[$i],
          'DeviceBrand_id' => $request->device_brand_id[$i],
          'spek_device' => $request->device_spec[$i],
          'harga_device' => $request->price[$i],
          'jumlah_device' => $request->amount[$i],
          'total_harga_device' => $request->total_price[$i]
        );
       }

      Transaction_in_detail::insert($tdin);

      $transaction_in->update(['idTransaction_in' => sprintf('TIN-%04d', $transaction_in->id)]);

      return redirect('/transactionsin')->with('success', 'Transaction success');
 }
```

Comment: your code give me another error `Array to string conversion`

Comment: Your code remove the error and the code is working now, but if i put more than 1 row in the table, it only save the first row.

Comment: @Aditya yes because you're inserting only 1 data, also if you want to save multiple you can add logic to loop the data

Comment: That's what i try to do in the question i made loop with `foreach` for saving multiple row of data. How to do it then?

Comment: Thanks It's working now, btw the `created_at` and `updated_at` is empty, is it okay to leave it like that?

Comment: @Aditya Glad it worked. You can set date automatically in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Your store method is a bit weird, this is what I think you should be doing:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'supplier_id' => 'required',
        'transaction_in_date' => 'required|before_or_equal:today',
        'device_type_id' => 'required',
        'device_brand_id' => 'required',
        'device_spec' => 'required|max:255',
        'price' => 'required',
        'amount' => 'required',
        'total_price' => 'required',
        'keterangan' => 'Nullable',
    ]);


    $transaction_in = new Transaction_in();
    $transaction_in->idTransaction_in = "0";
    $transaction_in->Supplier_id = $request->get('supplier_id');
    $transaction_in->tanggal_transaksi = $request->get('transaction_in_date');
    $transaction_in->save();

    Transaction_in_detail::create([
        'Transaction_in_id' => $transaction_in->id,
        'DeviceType_id' => $request->get('device_type_id'),
        'DeviceBrand_id' => $request->get('device_brand_id'),
        'spek_device' => $request->get('device_spec'),
        'harga_device' => $request->get('price'),
        'jumlah_device' => $request->get('amount'),
        'total_harga_device' => $request->get('total_price')
    ]);

    $transaction_in->update(['idTransaction_in' => sprintf('TIN-%04d', $transaction_in->id)]);

    return redirect('/transactionsin')->with('success', 'Transaction success');
}
```

Comment: your answer give me error `Array to string conversion`

Answer (score 0):

I think that all 10 rows became null because of the looping takes the count of the table columns.

your code

```
$transaction_in = new Transaction_in();
        $transaction_in->idTransaction_in = "0";
        $transaction_in->Supplier_id = $request->input('supplier_id');
        $transaction_in->tanggal_transaksi = $request->input('transaction_in_date');
        $transaction_in->save();

        foreach ( $transaction_in as $tin) {
            $tdin[] = [
                'Transaction_in_id' => $transaction_in->id[$tin],
                'DeviceType_id' => $transaction_in->device_type_id[$tin],
                'DeviceBrand_id' => $transaction_in->device_brand_id[$tin],
                'spek_device' => $transaction_in->device_spec[$tin],
                'harga_device' => $transaction_in->price[$tin],
                'jumlah_device' => $transaction_in->amount[$tin],
                'total_harga_device' => $transaction_in->total_price[$tin]
            ];
            Transaction_in_detail::insert($tdin);
        }
```

My Code

```
$transaction_in = new Transaction_in();
        $transaction_in->idTransaction_in = "0";
        $transaction_in->Supplier_id = $request->input('supplier_id');
        $transaction_in->tanggal_transaksi = $request->input('transaction_in_date');
        $transaction_in->save();
$transaction_in1 = new Transaction_in();
        foreach ( $transaction_in1 as $tin) {
            $tdin[] = [
                'Transaction_in_id' => $transaction_in1->id[$tin],
                'DeviceType_id' => $transaction_in1->device_type_id[$tin],
                'DeviceBrand_id' => $transaction_in1->device_brand_id[$tin],
                'spek_device' => $transaction_in1->device_spec[$tin],
                'harga_device' => $transaction_in1->price[$tin],
                'jumlah_device' => $transaction_in1->amount[$tin],
                'total_harga_device' => $transaction_in1->total_price[$tin]
            ];
            Transaction_in_detail::insert($tdin);
        }
```